# Is there a way find values associated with Lat/Long points that fall within radius of other Lat/Long Points?

Tags: r, latitude-longitude

I have over 1000 rows of lat/long data for different communities across the US in data table. Some of these communities are competitors and others are our own. Each of these communities has a number of units (apartments). There are many instances where multiple communities fall within 3 miles of each other. I am looking to find a way to do the following: 1)determine if each of the sites falls within a 3 mile radius of ALL other sites THEN 2) sum the "units" column of the sites that fall within that 3 mile radius. I would like two columns added to the data table... first column called "number of sites" and second is "number of units"

I already had written code to check to see if any other lat/lon fell within a 3 mile radius of each other but that is as far as I have gotten.

the main_df has over 400 columns. To simplify this I redid to show only the required columns..

colnames(main_df)
Result: Lat, Lon, Units

So the code to use in this question would be

```r
main_df<-cbind(main_df, X=((X=rowSums(distm (main_df[,2:1], 
     fun = distHaversine) / 1000<= 4.828032)/3)-1))
```

As mentioned before, I expect the result to add two additional columns to main_df. 
colnames(main_df)
Result: Lat, Lon, Units, number of sites, number of units

So kinda like this...

```
Lat         Lon      Units  #of Sites   #of Units
40.06127    -86.05604   80    2           184
41.15241    -85.12709   123   3           262
42.91640    -83.62937   125   1           200
39.67114    -86.07211   59    0           0
41.24905    -81.83060   200   4           387
```

Comment: The "geocomputation with R" book may be able to help you out: https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-operations.html#distance-relations. The "distance-relation" section I have bookmarked will hopefully help.

Comment: You are most of the way there.  My suggestion is the save the output from the `distm` function as variable.  Then you can search for rows where the rowSums > 1 and then use the `which` function to find the columns (thus the rows of your original data frame) of the nearby units.

Comment: @Dave2e , I tried doing what you said but I can't seem to get it working... I'm somewhat new to R. You mind showing me what you mean? I was able to get the # of sites column, but can't figure out how to get the # of Units column

Answer (score 0):

As per my earlier comment:
"My suggestion is the save the output from the distm function as variable. 
Then you can search for rows where the rowSums > 1 and then use the which function to find the columns (thus the rows of your original data frame) of the nearby units."

```
#Last rows added for testing
main_df<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="Lat    Lon  Units  
40.06127    -86.05604   80
41.15241    -85.12709   123
42.91640    -83.62937   125
39.67114    -86.07211   59
41.24905    -81.83060   200
40.061    -86.056   100
40.060    -86.0561   300")

library(geosphere)

#create and store distance matrix
#this will be a square matrix the length and width of as the number of rows in main_df.
# be aware of memory use.
distmat<-distm (main_df[,2:1], fun = distHaversine)/1000
# convert to logical matrix of units nearby, exclude same location.
distmat<-(distmat >0 & distmat <= 4.828032)

main_df$nearbysites <- rowSums(distmat)

#find rows where there is at least one other nearby sites
rowsnearby<-which(main_df$nearby >0)

#add place holding columns
main_df$sumunits<-0

#loop through all of the rows with more than 1 nearby site
for (i in rowsnearby){
  #find columns which are nearby, the column number is the same as the rows of main df that are close by
  targetrows<-which(distmat[i,]==TRUE)
  #find sum  
  main_df$sumunits[i]<-sum(main_df$Units[targetrows])
}
print(main_df)
```

Comment: thanks for the walkthrough... I am not sure the difference between yours and my code, but for some reason the code below got me a more accurate number for the sites..
```
distmat<-(distm (main_df[,2:1], 
     fun = distHaversine) / 1000<= 4.828032)
main_df$distmat <- ((rowSums(distmat)/3)-1)     
rowsnearby<-which(main_df$distmat >0)
main_df$sumunits<-0
for (i in rowsnearby){
    targetrows<-which(distmat[i,]==TRUE)
    main_df$sumunits[i]<-sum(main_df$`Total Units`[targetrows])
}
```

Comment: I am having a problem with capturing correct number for the `sumunits` column.. because it is summing everything INCLUDING it's own Units. EX: lat 40.06127  and lon  -86.05604 with 80 units (the first row i presented above) the `sumunits` should only include the 125 and 59 units from the other lat/lon. not it's own units and then the 125 and 59 amounts. So the correct total should be 184, not 264. does that make sense?

Comment: I edited the code slightly to just have the lat/long and units in the initial data frame.  For this test case it works as I would expect.  I am  not sure what you mean by more accurate number of sites? My distance matrix first calculates the distance and then it only tracks the ones > 0 and <3 miles.  If you have 2 points at the same location then it will lead to inaccurate results.  Your method, you need to correct so that you are not counting the origin.